# How can I get intellisense/autocompletion on compound React components in WebStorm?

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have the following React code:

```js
const MenuItem = ({ children, style }) => <h1 style={style}>{children}</h1>;

const Menu = ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>;
Menu.Item = MenuItem;

const App = () => (
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item>Item 1</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>Item 2</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>Item 3</Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);
```

The code works fine, but I get false warning in WebStorm when I use the compound components:
[image]

I also don't get any intellisense/autocompletion in WebStorm like I do with something like [react-native-paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/components/DataTable/DataTableCell/):
[image]

[image]

[image]

I do however get the intellisense/autocompletion in VSCode:
[image]

[image]

So I'm pretty sure it must be a WebStorm (JetBrains) issue, but I'm out of ideas. Anyone know how I can fix this on WebStorm?

Comment: Seems like this is an issue on all JetBrains IDEs. Follow their YouTrack issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-58577/JSX-components-are-not-resolved-when-using-dot-notation).